# Not a Function TypeError when Calling Object Method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, higher-order-functions, class-method

**Problem:**

When I try to call an object method in this particular way in JavaScript, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: listener.update is not a function
```

**My code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="library.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>

// manages listeners etc.
function Model() {
    var  listeners = [];

    this.addListener = function(listener) {
        listeners.push(listener);
    };

    // the model will call the listeners when "setting the selection"
    this.setSelection = function() {
        for (listener in listeners)
            listener.update();
    };
};

// test function that will be used as update
function moveon() {
    var answer = confirm("Ready to move on?");
    if (answer) window.location = "http://google.com";
}

// create a model and add a listener
var model = new Model();
var listnr = {};
listnr.update = moveon;
model.addListener(listnr);
// update listener
setTimeout(model.setSelection, 2000); // this doesn't work
// setTimeout(listnr.update, 2000);   // but this does

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Explanation of the code:**

The `Model` object manages a list of `listeners`, and calls their `update` method when some state has changed. In my example, this happens when `setSelection` is called.

**Note:**

The error isn't very insightful, and, if I uncomment the last line, `listnr.update` works fine.

**Question:**

Why do I get this error when the method is called from the model and/or how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please consider using a debugger before getting to SO

Comment: How so? What more would I figure out with a debugger? And what's SO? :p

Comment: you could inspect your listener object and see what is it's update property...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`model.setSelection` doesn't keep the reference to the object. If you don't need to support older browsers you can bind it to the object:

```
model.setSelection.bind(model)
```

If you do need to worry about older browsers, you can just use a small anonymous function:

```
function () { model.setSelection(); }
```

Either method will keep the object reference that is necessary for `setSelection` to work.

The reason `listnr.update` works is because that isn't the same type of function; you built a standalone non-object function and just set a reference to it into that object, so it works just fine. But if you tried that with model, you wouldn't be able to update the object itself.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't entirely understand, and I can't get it to work by using bind the way you propose, nor in some other ways I tried.

So if you want to pass a function to a object, you need to bind everything that function refers to or something like that? I'm a little disappointed in JavaScript then because that's not very nice if you want to use higher-order functions.

Comment: This is only an issue if you're trying to pass member functions around on their own, like you're trying to do in setTimeout. `setTimeout(function () { model.setSelection(); }, 2000)` should work just fine, given what you've pasted.

Comment: Ok, thanks I finally got it now! Your solution works indeed!